# Which Kafka Consumption product is best to sample data from all TopicPartition?

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to sample data from all Topics on a Kafka cluster. KStreams look like a good fit since it removes a lot of the boiler plate. However it doesn't seem like a good fit to query multiple topics per stream.

If I had, say, 50 topics, with varying partition numbers, would KStreams be a good way to consume some message from each Topic Partition? Or should I just write my own kafkaconsumer?

Comment: Regular consumer API can subscribe to a regex pattern

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to use some of the KStreams functionality, I would recommend going with the regular Java consumer API.  From the official Kafka docs, look under `Automatic Offset Committing` for a quick and dirty example:
https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
 props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
 props.put("group.id", "test");
 props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
 props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
 props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
 props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
 KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
 consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"));
 while (true) {
     ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
     for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
         System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s%n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
 }
```

The example above will consume from topics `foo` and `bar` simultaneously, regardless of how many partitions each of those topics has.